# Is there a way to both use the software I need, and be able to use Ubuntu upgraders instead of clean installing every LTS version?

Tags: upgrade

Like it says on the tin.

I've used Ubuntu for around five years now, and every upgrade has been a tribulation.  Running `do-release-upgrade` results in a partial upgrade, failed upgrade, or message that "third party" repositories will be disabled.

So, I wind up installing clean, a process I keep hearing should take "a couple hours" but which typically runs to a full weekend (for each machine) before I've got everything back the way I like it.

Apparently, this is one option; the other is to run only software from the Ubuntu repositories -- not very practical for a "daily driver" computer that needs to do everything I need a computer for (for a start, the game selection in the Ubuntu repos frankly sucks, for another, the supplied versions of productivity apps is typically a couple years out of date).

Is there a third option?  I run Libre Office (currently from their repo/ppa, because the one from Ubuntu is too old), SeaMonkey (ditto), and a number of other applications or plug-ins from third party sites.

Comment: Well, for a computer that is a "daily driver" (I presume you mean that it isn't a server but one that you use daily as a desktop), I have found no problems with sticking with only the Ubuntu repositories.  Having said that, I am not on LTS.  So, I do a `do-release-upgrade` every 6 months.  And I have problems perhaps 10-20% of the time (I upgrade multiple machines every 6 months...that's why I have enough samples to give such a percentage).  Thus, I almost never use PPAs.

Perhaps others have a more helpful opinion, but I suggest getting off LTS but update every 6 months.

Comment: Oh...  For servers that are used by multiple users for "serious" work, I stick to LTS and yeah...it's very painful each time.  Sometimes it works; sometimes it doesn't.  I'm just forced to admit that a lot of changes can happen in 2 years.  And yes, for servers, I almost never use PPAs.

Comment: The ubuntu installer will disable the ppas, but you can re-enable them after.  A clean install usually is better if you have modified and have many ppas, but upgrades are good also.

Comment: @Ray "I almost never use PPAs."  That's great if you don't ever play a game, use a program other than the "recommended" ones, or need something in a more current version than is in the Ubuntu repos.  My "daily driver" needs to support all these things.

Comment: Well, I don't quite agree with you that one has to have the latest versions to do what you listed.  And I use Ubuntu both at home and work and the software that it provides is more than enough for my needs.  Ubuntu has updates every 6 months which is already fairly frequent.  Perhaps you should take a step back and consider another Linux distribution, then?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a third (IMHO better) way.

First, by installing software from 3rd party repositories, you have accepted the responsibility of "does it work with the Ubuntu release I'm about to install?".

You have to research each 3rd party repository to see if it will run on the new release.

I assume you're already doing things like `/home` on a separate disk partition, and use of `/opt` where possible. See the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard at [FHS at Linux Foundation](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html) `/opt` can be created, but Linux software upgrades do NOT touch `/opt`.

Add your 3rd party repositories to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` rather than `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and disable them during *release* upgrades.

Keep your system up-to-date by doing

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

at least every week.

Maintain and use a canned procedure that does a simple "does this work?" test for each 3rd party tool.

By the above, I mean that *you* should make a list of each piece of software that you are concerned about.

Then, for EACH one, decide on a simple test of functionality. The test can be as simple as "Is the daemon running?", or a command-line invocation using tiny test data, or something more complex using `expect` or a GUI simulator. The goal is to produce a small testable (harmless) invocation of the software, and report the name and result, then wrap the tests up in a script so you can type a single command and do:

```
$ ./run_tests
First_Program:     OK
Program_Two:    BAD 
Prog_3:    OK
...
7 Tests run, 6 OK 1 BAD
```

Run this set of tests before and after each upgrade.

When a test fails ,(`BAD`) investigate. Find which system packages were upgraded (in `/var/log/apt/`).

Read the package's `Change Log` with `apt changelog packagename`.

Determine which change caused the failure, and figure out what to do (Rebuild the failed test's software (if you have the source), reinstall the package-from-elsewhere, report to the developers-from-elsewhere, ...).

For inspiration, read `man run-parts`.

Comment: I have weekly (at least) upgrades, been doing that for years.  '/home' on a separate partition for years.  Not sure what you mean by `/opt` where possible.  Really not sure about your "does this work" script suggestion...

Comment: Looking at this again, I don't see how it's a different option.  It does nothing to alleviate the "you can't actually upgrade" problem.  You're just telling me, in effect "bite the bullet, it's your responsibility."

Comment: @ZeissIkon "bite the bullet, it's your responsibility" is sort of what I wanted to tell you, but I didn't have the heart to say it...  Presumably, things that are in the Ubuntu software repositories have been tested to make sure there are minimal or no conflicts.  Anyone who makes their software available via a PPA has not done that check -- and they do not need to.  Indeed, it is the price you pay for deviating from the standard repository.